# #define directive with multiple replacements?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, wxwidgets, preprocessor-directive

I am relatively new to programming, and I am trying to learn to use wxWidgets in C++ (with Visual Studio 2010).

I was looking through the wxWidgets header file "app.h" and I see some `#define` directives that I can't understand.  Here is an example:

```
#define wxIMPLEMENT_APP(appname)            \
   wxIMPLEMENT_WX_THEME_SUPPORT            \
   wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_THEMES(appname)"
```

I'm used to seeing #define with one "identifier" and one "replacement", so I can't understand if this macro has two "identifiers" (`wxIMPLEMENT_APP(appname)` and `wxIMPLEMENT_WX_THEME_SUPPORT`) and one "replacement" (`wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_THEMES (appname)`), or one "identifier" (`wxIMPLEMENT_APP(appname)`) and two "replacements" (`wxIMPLEMENT_WX_THEME_SUPPORT` and `wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_THEMES(appname)`).

How am I to understand this macro?

I tried looking online and in text books, searching under "macros", "pre-processor directives", "text replacement macros", "#define directive", and similar, but I could not find any examples with explanation that look like the one I have here.

Comment: Advice: Try to keep macros as last resort.

Comment: Using your nomenclature, your macro has one identifier and one replacement. The identifier is `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(appname)`, the replacement is `wxIMPLEMENT_WX_THEME_SUPPORT wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_THEMES(appname)"`.

Comment: Rob: thanks for clarifying the roles of identifier and replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *preprocessor macro* has a single replacement split across multiple lines. The `\` at the end of the line lets you write a single "logical" line on multiple lines of text.

Everything that follows `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(appname)` will be placed in the text of the program when `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(appname)` pattern is *matched*; presumably, both these definitions will be further processed by the preprocessor, because they look like references to other macro definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your help; in addition to answering my specific question, you helped clarify some of the terminology for me.