# C pre-processor define directive with multiple replacements

Tags: c

```
/*
 * Recommended alloc parameters for "small" contexts that are never expected
 * to contain much data (for example, a context to contain a query plan).
 */

    #define ALLOCSET_SMALL_MINSIZE   0
    #define ALLOCSET_SMALL_INITSIZE  (1 * 1024)
    #define ALLOCSET_SMALL_MAXSIZE   (8 * 1024)
    #define ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES \
        ALLOCSET_SMALL_MINSIZE, ALLOCSET_SMALL_INITSIZE, ALLOCSET_SMALL_MAXSIZE
```

I don't understand last marco, I use

```
printf("%d", ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES);
```

then warning:

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

and also return 0.

similar post I found: [#define directive with multiple replacements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030660/define-directive-with-multiple-replacements)

---

Update: Jumped around source code, got it.
function like

```
foo(size_t,size_t,size_t)
```

can just use

```
foo(ALLOCSET_DEFAULT_SIZES)
```

Comment: `ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES` expands eventually to `0, (1 * 1024), (8 * 1024)`, i.e. to 3 values, and your `printf` specifier mentions only 1 (the 1 `%d`).

Comment: ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES now is like a int array?  @wohlstad

Comment: No it's not an array. The preprocessor is simply replacing strings in your source code before the compiler gets it. The line `printf("%d", ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES);` becomes `printf("%d", 0, (1 * 1024), (8 * 1024));` after the preprocessor is doing macro replacement. I suggest you read about preprocessor macros and how they work.

Comment: The preprocessor is not aware of arrays whatsoever. It works with tokens.

Comment: @jian No, just a list of comma separated values.  What that means semantically is context dependent.  Here it is a list of variadic arguments for `printf`, and you particular compiler helpfully checks for format specifier mismatch.  The error is all about the resulting printf call, and nothing to do with the macro.  Clearly you need `"%d, %d, %d"` to print all three values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following snippet:

```
#define ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES \
        ALLOCSET_SMALL_MINSIZE, ALLOCSET_SMALL_INITSIZE, ALLOCSET_SMALL_MAXSIZE
```

The macro `ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES` gets replaced with:

```
ALLOCSET_SMALL_MINSIZE, ALLOCSET_SMALL_INITSIZE, ALLOCSET_SMALL_MAXSIZE
```

which gets replaced with:

```
0,
(1 * 1024),
(8 * 1024)
```

which are separate arguments. Then in the call to `printf ()`:

```
printf("%d", ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES);
```

`ALLOCSET_SMALL_SIZES` gets replaced with `0, (1 * 1024), (8 * 1024)`

Or,

```
printf ("%d", 0, (1 * 1024), (8 * 1024));
```

Hence the warning.

---

**Fix:**

Replace it with:

```
printf ("%d %d %d", 0, (1 * 1024), (8 * 1024));
```

See: [Why use Macros in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358232/20017547) and [What are C macros useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/653839/20017547)